# Log rabbitmq message headers in graylog

Tags: logging, rabbitmq, graylog

I am logging messages sent to rabbitMQ using graylog by routing all messages posted to an exchange to a queue specifying # as routing key. And then configuring that queue in graylog as AMQP input source. This works fine but I could log only the messages and not the headers. Is there any way to extract and log headers as well?

Comment: In general, the Graylog community forums might be a better place to ask Graylog-related questions: https://community.graylog.org/

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, the Graylog AMQP transport doesn't process the message headers (as of Graylog 2.4.0).

If you think there is a valid use case, you can create a feature request for Graylog on GitHub at https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-server/issues.